# How to update hazelcast map in all nodes if updated from one node?

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-cloud

I have one microservice let's say **StudentProfile**, and deployed this  in 2 nodes **xxxx:8081** and **yyyy:8081**.
In this microservice I have created hazelcast map where I am storing data of student with **map.put(roll_number, student_object)**. Now when I am updating some student from **xxxx:8081**, its get updated here but when I try to fetch the data of same student from **yyyy:8081**, I get old data.

My question is that how do I sync(share) that Map in both the nodes so that If I make changes from one node then they should be reflected from another node as well. Is there some configuration changes which I need to make?

Please ask me further details if above explanation doesn't makes sense. I am new to it and trying to learn how  it works.

Comment: When you update the data do you do another `map.put(roll_number, studient_object)` in one node, then `map.get(roll_number)` in the second node ?

Comment: Yes I can do this

Comment: Does my answer help any ? If one node can put and the other get, then connectivity exists, and there should be no reason to get a stale value unless you have added configuration specifically for that

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of Hazelcast for [IMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.html) should give you what you want.

If the two nodes are connected, you will see a log line in each similar to

```
Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [1.2.3.4]:5701 - aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
    Member [5.6.7.8]:5701 - bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb this
]
```

If you find the map with `HazelcastInstance.getMap("63149165")`, both nodes are using the same map with the given name.

If *any* node does `map.put("hello", new Date())`, then *any* node can do `map.get("hello")` to retrieve the value that was inserted.

Default behavior is for synchronous replication. You won't get the previous value unless you have modified the configuration, and if you have modified the configuration from default this won't be a surprise.

What is important to note is you get a defensive copy of the data in Hazelcast.

If you do `map.get("hello")` you get a copy of the data value associated with that key. If you modify that copy but do not then re-insert it in the grid, the grid copy doesn't change. So if you do `map.get("hello")` again you will continue to get the original value.